# NSComparisonResult options

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

In my iOS app I have implemented a table view from core data and a search bar. At the current status, the search only shows the fields that begin with the search string, but what I want is to show the fields that include search text of at least three characters in length.

That´s is my code for the search function:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    NSLog(@"Previous Search Results were removed.");
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    for (Person *person in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [person.firstname isEqualToString:scope])
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [person.firstname compare:searchText
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                NSLog(@"Adding person.firstname '%@' to searchResults as it begins with search text '%@'", person.firstname, searchText);
                [self.searchResults addObject:person];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You are kindly requested to teach me the way to make the search as wanted, any field which has search string of at least three characters in length.
Thank you.

Comment: Stupid comment, I'm sure, but you presumably mean contains at least three characters from the search string in the same order as they appear in the search string? So the search string could be "abcdef" and that would match "stcdepqr" but not "edabfc"?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry....thank you tommy:)An example: search string:#10, selected fields: task #10 / group #101, etc..

Comment: Does this mean searchText #10 would be matched with #0120 as it matches 3 characters from the searchText or you are looking for 3 consecutive characters?

Comment: Hi AYan, I mean consecutive characters...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method, best suited to your requirements, in my view would be to use a NSPredicate to filter out the `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` array and use it. A NSPredicate can be applied on any NSArray to filter out its results sending `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` message to that array instance. So my suggestion is to use some code like the following:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    Person* person = evaluatedObject;
    NSString* firstName = person.firstname;

    //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
    if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [firstName isEqualToString:scope])  {
        return ([firstName rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
    } 
    return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}
```

Comment: thank you Ayan, but I have to ask you where should I insert your code.??

Comment: @mvasco please see my edited answer with modified `filterContentForSearchText` method for you.

Comment: Thanks again Ayan, but using your code doesn't show any filtering..there is no error message, and the app doesn't hung up. As example: there are 10 records, each record has a first name field, the content of the firstname fields are: 1. task #1 2. task #2 3. task #3, etc. Running with my code,  i have to search for the whole string, for example: task # -> shows all 10 records; task #1 -> shows records 1 and 10, task #1 and task #10. Running with your code, if I search for: task #1 -> show all records...

Comment: What I need is to search for: #1, and the records to be shown must be task #1 and task #10, or if I search for ask, all records must be shown, then all records have the string ask in them (task)...

Comment: @mvasco the reason you are getting all records is very simple. you have asked for a solution that matches at least 3 chars of your search term and I have crafted the NSRegularExpression accordingly. So when you enter "task #1" as search term it has chars 't','a','s','k',' ','#','1' and at least 3 chars matches with all items in your source list "task #1", "task #2", etc. Now it seems that your requirement is somewhat different. So I am going to edit my answer again and gonna let you know shortly.

Comment: That is fine, thank you Ayan, you have helped me a lot.... may I ask you another question?

Comment: @mvasco sorry have I missed it. Unfortunately, according to the site norms, this comment section is not for asking questions in SO,  and so I can't encourage you to do that here. And even more unfortunately, I cant set up a chat session with you as you dont have enough reputation, yet. So my only suggestion is to post your new question to SO again, if you can't find a resolution or help from any source. I would try to track if you post one. Thanks

Comment: Thanks in any case, I understand your position, I am very new here at Stackoverflow. If I can't resolve my new issue, I will put a new question.....You have been very nice to me... :)

Answer (score 1):

To start the discussion at least, the naive brute force approach:

```
// get a set of all substrings; using a set means these will be deduplicated
NSMutableSet *substrings = [NSMutableSet set];
for(NSInteger index = 0; index < searchText.length - 3; index++)
    [substrings addObject:[searchText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)]];

// search every person for every single last possibility
[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
for(Person *person in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
{
    // ... scope and whatever else tests here ...

    for(NSString *string in substrings)
    {
        if([person.firstname rangeOfString:string].location != NSNotFound)
        {
             [self.searchResults addObject:person];
             break; // exit the string in substrings loop early
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tommy, I am getting an error: No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector rangeOfSubstring. And what part of my code has to be substituted by your proposal?

Comment: Sorry; I just typed it in here directly and obviously the earlier call to `substringWithRange:` affected my thinking. It's `rangeOfString:`, not `rangeOfSubstring:` since the thing you're passing isn't necessarily a substring — it may not be found at all.

Comment: Thanks again, Tommy, but now I don't know where in my code do I have to put your code instead of mine...sorry, but I am a completely iOS newbie...

Comment: Tommy, already solved, take a look at Ayan's code...thank you in any case. have a nice day

Comment: ... not to mention that the answer you've selected and mine appear to have read your question separately: the other will (i) check that your search string is at least three characters; then (ii) check if it is within any person's first name. Mine will check whether any three characters from anywhere within the search string are anywhere within a person's first name. Which it does just by running much the exact same test as the accepted answer but iterating through all the possibilities — hence the 'brute force' comment.